# Why does g++ compile this?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, syntax, segmentation-fault

Recently, after being very tired, I wrote the following code:

```
GLfloat* array = new GLfloat(x * y * z);
```

Which, of course should have been:

```
GLfloat* array = new GLfloat[x * y * z];
```

(Note the square brackets as opposed to the parenthesis.)

As far as I know, the first form is not valid, but g++ compiled it. Sure, it spat out a completely incomprehensible segfault, but it compiled.

Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
GLfloat* array = new GLfloat(x * y * z);
```

Creates a pointer called `array` to an object of type `GLfloat` with a value of `x * y * z`.

Answer (score 9):

Well, the result of `new T()` is a `T*`, so `new GLFloat` would return a GLFloat*. As long as `x*y*z` is valid to pass to the GLFloat constructor, it's valid code.

Answer (score 7):

It's the same sort of thing as:

```
int * p = new int(42);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first expression is a pointer to a GLfloat with value (x*y*z), which is perfectly legal.